# Driver for canon pixma mg5520 needed

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I'm ready to go back to windows 7 if i can't get driver for my canon pixma mg5520. ubuntu recognizes the printer but it is not in list of printers with available drivers.

Answer (score 3):

My new printer Canon MG5520:

> Canon offers linux drivers for MG series of all-in-ones. Go to [this](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG5540.aspx) page and follow the instructions. There are both source code and packaged versions of the software. Also you will probably need to download both IJ drivers and scanner drivers.

After downloading the packages from Canon as previously answer, I untar'ed, unzipped files, and executed `sudo ./install.sh`, I ran into "rpm install errors", until I did the following:

1. `cd` into extracted directory, then `cd packages` directory
2. converted .rpm packages to .deb packages using alien `sudo alien *filter*64.rpm`
3. modified install script - my edit command `sudo vi ./install.sh` as follows:

   a. When packages is converted, package version is incremented so change:
     Line 24 in my file: `C_version="4.00-2"` <----Just change number after '-'
     to whatever is new number in converted filename.

   b. Line 26 in my file: Changed `C_default_system="rpm"` to `C_default_system="deb"`

Note: You man need to install `alien` package using apt-get

Comment: It seems you downloaded the wrong archive. Just scroll down and download the package for debian based systems.

Answer (score 0):

If us is detecting the printer then the best idea is to go under settings and then additional drivers. This should automatically detect and install the device software. Also this thread my help http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=38995 Although it is for a diffrent printer.

Answer (score 0):

Canon offers linux drivers for MG series of all-in-ones. Go to this [page](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG5540.aspx) and follow the instructions. There are both source code and packaged versions of the software (you need the one for debian based systems not the `.rpm` one). Also you will probably need to download both IJ drivers and scanner drivers.

After downloading, extract the contents of the downloaded file. Inside the created directory there should be a file named `install.sh`

Make sure that it's executable and type `chmod +x install.sh` if it's not. After that you can execute it by typing

`sudo ./install.sh`

Enter your password and follow the instructions that appear on screen.

Comment: I downloaded the IJ and cononscan files. How do Iha execute the install of the driver files? The computer recognizes the printer and printer has downloaded a firmware update. I have sent print jobs to the printer but the jobs will not print from the queue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Being a neophyte to linux, I do not know how to determine if a file is exacutable or how to make a file executable by inputing Linux command line syntex. I found the install.sh but I don't know how to input the chmod +x install.sh I am hoping hmayag will respond.

Comment: I found the termianl. I have purchased an ubuntu linux book from Amazon. I hope that will help to understand the command line. I remember DOS so it should not be too bad.

Comment: Good for you. Enjoy the experience! Shortcut for opening terminal is `Ctrl+Alt+T`. Type `exit` to end the terminal session.

Comment: Thanks hmayag. I was expecting ubuntu to be point and click with self installing drivers, but it seems there is more to it.